# IBM MQ .NET (amqmdnetstd) Shared Subscriptions enquiry

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

Does anyone know this feature is actually available for the amqmdnetstd Library?

I couldn't find any concrete examples or info that suggests this. I am able to setup regular subscriptions which are able to read new messages as they are placed in the topic but I am looking to have multiple subscribers sharing the same subscription to where any of them could receive the message as it arrives.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Shared subscriptions is a concept of JMS 2.0. IBM MQ JMS supports Shared subscriptions. IBM MQ .NET which is the native API for MQ does not support it. However IBM XMS .NET which is a JMS API implementation in .NET supports "Cloned Subscription" which is quite similar to Shared Subscription. More details here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119140_.htm

You will need to use the latest version of XMS .NET to make use of Cloned Subscription. Here is more details of the APAR https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IV96489

You will need to set connection factory property "CLONESUPP"and the value to XMSC.WMQ_CLONE_ENABLED.